# Carregar ComboBox com string concatenada

Tags: c#

Código que carrega a `comboBox`:

```
private void frmAdicionarProdutos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frmAdicionarProdutos_Load);
             string serverName = "localhost";
             string port = "5432";
             string userName = "postgres";
             string password = "adm";
             string databaseName = "GE";
             NpgsqlConnection conn = null;
             string ConnString = null;

             ConnString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                           serverName, port, userName, password, databaseName);

            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string cmdCarregar = String.Format("SELECT CONCAT(id_produto,' ', nome,' ', preco) FROM PRODUTOS;");
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdCarregar, conn))
                {
                    NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(dr);

                    cbProdutos.DisplayMember = "nome";
                    cbProdutos.ValueMember = "id_produto";
                    cbProdutos.DataSource = dt;
                    conn.Close();
                }     
            }
        }
```

Montei o `select` para concatenar o que preciso mostrar no comboBox, porém não sei como informo no `DisplayMember`. Da maneira que está, quando executo o programa ele carrega a comboBox com o seguinte valor: `System.Data.DataRowView`.

Comment: Pô, jovem. Eu quero te ajudar, mas tem tanta coisa ruim aí que eu nem sei por onde começar.

Comment: kkk Eu tenho noção disso.. você não é o primeiro a falar isso :( mas me ajuda nisso ai.. porque o select está correto, testei no banco.. só na hora de mostrar que tá zoado..

Comment: então... `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frmAdicionarProdutos_Load);` dentro do próprio evento eu nunca vi...ainda bem que o load só executa uma vez né...rs tira isso daí que não tá servindo pra nada.. sobre as outras coisas 'ruins' vou considerar que é só seus testes e que isso não irá pro resultado final (espero) hehe vlw

Comment: Não está duplicado, lá era duvida de como carregar, aqui é duvida de como mostrar os itens concatenados..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá...
você tem que trazer as colunas no seu select, e nem precisa do String.Format :

```
 string cmdCarregar = "SELECT CONCAT(id_produto,' ', nome,' ', preco) as descricao, id_produto FROM PRODUTOS;";
```

Repare que estou montando uma coluna concatenada, e ainda assim trazendo o id_produto em outra coluna.

```
using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnString))
{
    conn.Open();

    string cmdCarregar = "SELECT CONCAT(id_produto,' ', nome,' ', preco) as descricao, id_produto FROM PRODUTOS;";

    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdCarregar, conn))
    {
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);

        cbProdutos.DisplayMember = "descricao";
        cbProdutos.ValueMember = "id_produto";
        cbProdutos.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }     
}
```

Por fim, basta colocar no DisplayMember, o nome da coluna que foi criada na query, a que veio concatenada: `descricao`

O resto, permanece igual.

espero ter ajudado

Comment: Isso ai que eu precisava, sabe como coloco mais espaços entre os campos? é só eu ir colocando os `' '`

Comment: sim, particularmente, colocaria outro separador...aí é preferência =] `CONCAT(id_produto,'-', nome,' | R$', preco)`

Comment: Verdade, fez mais sentido! Obrigado.